# Doom Emacs -- Use a library

Tags: start-up, doom, libraries

Running Doom Emacs 2.0.9 on Emacs 27.1.

A library org-inlinetask provides some functionality I need.

I can `SPC h P org-inlinetask` to open the library. Then I can `SPC c e` to evaluate buffer. This makes the functionality available to me.

But all is lost when I restart Emacs. And I have to do these two steps again.

How do I ensure that the functionality provided by the library is available on starting Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `(require 'org-inlinetask)` to your init.el file.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. That does it. The only change I made was to add that line to my `config.el` file --- as required in Doom Emacs.